# Seeking how to prevent blank new item from adding to unordered list

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript. I set up a simple unordered to-do list where items can be added and removed. Unfortunately, blank list items are also added when the create button is pressed.  How do I change the Javascript code so it will not add a blank list item and will only alert the user to add a valid item when the item is blank?

Besides the code below, I have also tried putting the if statement inside the createItem function but then the alert pops up for all items and the blank ones still get created.

```
let ourForm = document.getElementById("ourForm");
let ourField = document.getElementById("ourField");
let ourList = document.getElementById("ourList");

ourForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createItem(ourField.value);
});

function createItem(x) {
    let ourHTML = `<li>${x} <button onclick="deleteItem(this)">Delete</button></li>`;
    ourList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", ourHTML);
    ourField.value = "";
    ourField.focus();
};

function emptyItem() {
    if (ourField.value == "") {
        alert("Enter a valid to-do item");
        return false;
    };
};

function deleteItem(elementToDelete) {
    elementToDelete.parentElement.remove();
};
```

Comment: You could add `if (!emptyItem()) return false;` before `createItem(ourField.value);` on form submit event

Answer (score 0):

You created the `emptyItem()` function but you never called it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `x.length > 0` to check if the item to be added is empty. Try this

```
let ourForm = document.getElementById("ourForm");
let ourField = document.getElementById("ourField");
let ourList = document.getElementById("ourList");

ourForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  createItem(ourField.value);
});

function createItem(x) {
  if (x.length > 0) {
    let ourHTML = `<li>${x} <button onclick="deleteItem(this)">Delete</button></li>`;
    ourList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", ourHTML);
    ourField.value = "";
    ourField.focus();
  } else {
    alert("Enter a valid to-do item");
  }
}

function deleteItem(elementToDelete) {
  elementToDelete.parentElement.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding

```
if (!emptyItem()) return false;
```

Before `createItem(ourField.value);` in form submit event.

But in this context `!emptyItem()` is not very clear, you could change the definition of the function to

```
function emptyItem() {
    if (ourField.value == "") {
        alert("Enter a valid to-do item");
        return true;
    };

    return false;
};
```

And change the verification to be easy to understand the intention

`if (emptyItem()) return false;`

```js
let ourForm = document.getElementById("ourForm");
let ourField = document.getElementById("ourField");
let ourList = document.getElementById("ourList");

ourForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();


    if (emptyItem()) return false;

    createItem(ourField.value);
});

function createItem(x) {
    let ourHTML = `<li>${x} <button onclick="deleteItem(this)">Delete</button></li>`;
    ourList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", ourHTML);
    ourField.value = "";
    ourField.focus();
};

function emptyItem() {
    if (ourField.value == "") {
        alert("Enter a valid to-do item");
        return true;
    };

    return false;
};

function deleteItem(elementToDelete) {
    elementToDelete.parentElement.remove();
};
```

```html
<form name="ourForm" id="ourForm">
    <input type="text" id="ourField" name="ourField">

    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>

<ul id="ourList"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I changed the order of my original code this also worked and was simple:

```
let ourForm = document.getElementById("ourForm");
let ourField = document.getElementById("ourField");
let ourList = document.getElementById("ourList");

ourForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();  
  createItem(ourField.value);
});

function createItem(x) {
  let ourHTML = `<li>${x} <button onclick="deleteItem(this)">Delete</button></li>`;
  if (ourField.value == "") {
    alert("Enter a valid to-do item");
    return false;
  };
  ourList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", ourHTML);
  ourField.value = "";
  ourField.focus();
};

function deleteItem(elementToDelete) {
  elementToDelete.parentElement.remove();
};
```